# 301 Redirect not properly redirecting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to implement a simple redirect on a Wordpress site.

Here's the line in question:

```
Redirect 301 http://bureaudebureau.com http://bureaudebureau.com/category/furniture
```

Here is the entire .htaccess file I am using:

```
AddHandler php-stable .php

Redirect 301 http://bureaudebureau.com http://bureaudebureau.com/category/furniture

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a `301` (which is a permanent redirect) from your root website to `/category/furniture` subfolders ??

Comment: I want visitors to http://bureaudebureau.com to be redirected to the furniture category archive, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure, then you can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess

```
AddHandler php-stable .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ category/furniture [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```